# Unable to read JSON response, integer turns into NULL

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am coding this fulfillment in Firebase for Google's Dialogflow chatbot.

I am trying to get the value of **Count** but it is appearing as null.

Here's the API response:

> [{"Count":1385}]

Here's my code:

```
function getCount(cloudFnResponse) {

    var pathString = "//someApiPath";
    console.log('Path string: ' + pathString);


    var request = https.get({
    //method:"GET",
    host: "//someApiHost",
    path: pathString
    }, function(response) {

        var json = "";
        console.log("Log1=> response is: " + response);
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log("log2=> Received json response: " + chunk);
            json += chunk;

         });
         response.on('end', function() {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);

            console.log("log3=> jsonData is: " + jsonData);
            var count = jsonData[0].Count;

            console.log("log4=> count is: " + JSON.stringify(count));

            var chat = "Count is " + count;
            console.log("log5=> chat is: " + chat);
            cloudFnResponse.send(buildChatResponse(chat));
         });

    });
}
```

I've added logs for debugging, here's the output log from the above code:

```
log1=> response is: [object Object]
log2=> Received json response: [{"Count":null}]
log3=> jsonData is: [object Object]
log4=> bot count is: undefined
log5=> chat is: Count is undefined
```

I am also thinking maybe it had something to do with the API response, the integer part: 1385, is not enclosed in double quotes?

Any suggestion on how can I successfully get the integer value? It keeps on turning to null.

Comment: Response appears to be an array so you should do  var count = jsonData[0].count; Also when you JSON.stringify(Count) there is a capital C instead of lowercase

Comment: apologies about the casing, corrected them now. I actually replaced the original variable names (and so as the API path) to scrub off some potentially sensitive info.

It is still appearing as null with the correct casing of variables.

Answer (score 1):

As per API Response, update function like this -

you should use `Count` and not `count` as it returns as `Count`

```js
function getCount(cloudFnResponse) {

  var pathString = "//someApiPath";
  console.log('Path string: ' + pathString);


  var request = https.get({
    //method:"GET",
    host: "//someApiHost",
    path: pathString
  }, function(response) {

    var json = "";
    console.log("Log1=> response is: " + response);
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      console.log("log2=> Received json response: " + chunk);
      json += chunk;

    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);

      console.log("log3=> jsonData is: " + jsonData);
      var Count = jsonData[0].Count;

      console.log("log4=> count is: " + JSON.stringify(Count));

      var chat = "Count is " + Count;
      console.log("log5=> chat is: " + chat);
      cloudFnResponse.send(buildChatResponse(chat));
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the casing as suggested, though as you can see before that part of the code, in "log2" it is already appearing as null.

Comment: @brian3415 that means your API is not returning `Count`, please debug API

Comment: but when I access the path in the browser it is returning the Count.